# Snowflake - parsing XML specific value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get specific value from XML.
My xml looks like in the example
**<w:KV w:Key="cardtype" w:Value="MC" />**
So I need to get "cardtype" value, in this case result should be "MC"
What query should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GET function:

```
select get( parse_xml('<w:KV w:Key="cardtype" w:Value="MC" />') , '@w:Value' ) ;
```

Returns "MC"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I need in this case is to get any value that can be for "cardtype"